# How to load JSON from variable, object

Tags: javascript, json

I have this code:

```
var browserName = "chrome";

    function getBrowserHack() {

        var browsersStack = {
            "chrome" : {
                "hacks": {
                    "global" : "!!window.chrome;",
                    "version" : {
                        "32" : "!!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;"
                    }
                }
            },
            "firefox" : {
                "hacks": {
                    "global" : "!!window.sidebar;",
                    "version" : {
                        "2": "(function x(){})[-6]=='x';"
                    }
                }
            },
            "safari" : {
                "hacks" : {
                    "global" : "/constructor/i.test(window.HTMLElement);"
                }
            },
            "opera" : {
                "hacks" : {
                    "global" : "window.opera && window.opera.version() == X;"
                }
            }
        }
        return $.getJSON(browsersStack, function(data){
            var browsers = data[browserName];
            return browsers;
        });
    }
```

i need to return function with this JSON data, and i have an error `[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)`. What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstood `getJSON`, you have the JS Object already right there in your code, try this:

```
function getBrowserHack(browserName) {

    var browsersStack = {
        "chrome" : {
            "hacks": {
                "global" : "!!window.chrome;",
                "version" : {
                    "32" : "!!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;"
                }
            }
        },
        "firefox" : {
            "hacks": {
                "global" : "!!window.sidebar;",
                "version" : {
                    "2": "(function x(){})[-6]=='x';"
                }
            }
        },
        "safari" : {
            "hacks" : {
                "global" : "/constructor/i.test(window.HTMLElement);"
            }
        },
        "opera" : {
            "hacks" : {
                "global" : "window.opera && window.opera.version() == X;"
            }
        }
    }
    return browsersStack[browserName];
}

// Now get the browserhack by calling:
var browserHack = getBrowserHack('chrome');
```

Comment: Had a huge typo in there, fixed it just now

Answer (score 0):

`getJSON` is an Ajax function. It makes an HTTP request to a URL (the first argument) and processes the response with the function used in the second argument.

You don't even have any JSON. You just have an object.

```
// Remove this line
return $.getJSON(browsersStack, function(data){
// Keep these two lines
    // but use the correct variable name here - you aren't copying the object to data
    var browsers = browsersStack[browserName];
    return browsers;
// Remove this line
});
```